# how to inject quartz's job with ninject?

Tags: ninject, quartz.net, inject

I use ninject and quartz.net in my application and I want to inject job with ninject,But I do not know how to ,because all I know is that jobdetail is created by class of Jobimpl instead of an instance,such as:

```
JobBuilder.Create<SomeJob>()
```

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to implement an `Quartz.Spi.IJobFactory` - which uses an `IResolutionRoot` to create the job (see below for implementation).
Then configure the scheduler to use it: `Quartz.IScheduler.JobFactory = kernel.Get<NinjectJobFactory>();`
(or, alternatively: `Quartz.IScheduler.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory(kernel);`)

---

```
public class NinjectJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public NinjectJobFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob)this.resolutionRoot.Get(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        this.resolutionRoot.Release(job);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Quartz.IScheduler.JobFactory = *new* NinjectJobFactory()` makes more sense

Comment: yeah maybe. But i think it's rather along the lines of  `Quartz.IScheduler.JobFactory = kernel.Get<NinjectJobFactory>()` or you let the `NinjectJobFactory` be injected.. that's why I left it out ;-)