# c# .NET MVC 4 - How do I create Quartz jobs that use Ninject services?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, quartz.net

I am using .NET MVC 4. All services are injected using Ninject. I am trying to schedule a job using Quartz. Right now, jobs are registered in `Global.asax` as follows:

`Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    // ... configuration stuff

    ScheduledJobs.RegisterJobs();
}
```

`ScheduleJobs.cs` has the `ScheduledJobs` class, which creates jobs with triggers and adds them to a standard schedule.

In `ScheduleJobs.cs`:

```
public class ScheduledJobs {

  public static void RegisterJobs() {
    IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

    scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobUsingService>()
        .WithIdentity("JobUsingService")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s =>
            s.WithIntervalInHours(1)
            .OnEveryDay()
            .StartingDailyAt(new Quartz.TimeOfDay(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute)))
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
  }
}
```

This is the job code:

```
public class JobUsingService : IJobUsingService, IJob {

   private ISomeService someService;

   public JobUsingService(ISomeService _someService) {
       someService = _someService;
   }

   public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
       someService.someStuff();
   }
}
```

The problem is that `JobUsingService` has to be initialized using Ninject so that `SomeService` is injected into it (also by Ninject). Calling `IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<JobUsingService>().WithIdentity("JobUsingService").Build();` skips over the Ninject injection and creates a regular instance of the class without injecting the necessary services.

How can I create a job of type `JobUsingService` using Ninject?

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810793/how-to-inject-quartzs-job-with-ninject/22812433#22812433) suggests creating a `NinjectJobFactory`, but I am not sure how to actually use this factory and create jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, we needed to add the NinjectJobFactory class described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810793/how-to-inject-quartzs-job-with-ninject/22812433#22812433)

We also had to make the following changes:

In `ScheduleJobs.cs`:

```
public class ScheduledJobs {

    public static void RegisterJobs() {
        // Create a new kernel and create the necessary bindings
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IJobUsingService>().To<JobUsingService>();

        // Create a scheduler and give it the Ninject job factory created earlier
        IScheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory(kernel);

        // Create the job with the interface which will be injected
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<IJobUsingService>()
             .WithIdentity("IJobUsingService")
             .Build();

         // Create the trigger
         ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
             .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s =>
                 s.WithIntervalInHours(23)
                  .OnEveryDay()
                  .StartingDailyAt(new Quartz.TimeOfDay(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute)))
             .Build();

         scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you'll have to use the `NinjectJobFactory` of the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22812433/684096). In an app initialization routine (`Application_Start` or wherever you configure the application to use ninject. Just after the creation of the kernel) you have to do:

```
Quartz.IScheduler.JobFactory = kernel.Get<NinjectJobFactory>();
```

or alternatively:

```
Quartz.IScheduler.JobFactory = new NinjectJobFactory(kernel);
```

(doesn't matter which, they're completely interchangeable)

From then on Quarty will create the job types (`JobUsingService` using the `NinjectJobFactory` which in turns uses the `kernel` to create the jobs...